# ODOO 10 Hide decimal numbers

Tags: python, odoo-10

In the Qweb report i  want to hide a number if it has a decimal (the whole number not just the numbers after the decimal point)

I tried this `t-if="int(l.product_uom_qty)"` but it's only working with numbers<1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_integer` on Float:

```
>>> (-2.0).is_integer()
True
>>> (3.2).is_integer()
False
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that yesterday and it didn't work ...I actually found the answer now

t-if="l.product_uom_qty % 1 == 0"


Thanks for helping

Comment: Like this '(l.product_uom_qty).is_integer' and like this 'is_integer(l.product_uom_qty)' and they both didn't work

Comment: The first will return an object reference and the second will raise a `NameError` exception.

Comment: I think using this method is more readable and cleaner. Try  `l.product_uom_qty.is_integer()` and call it it's a method not a attribute, and don't use parentheses to surround the field name it's all ready a float object just access it's property directly.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer

For anyone having the same problem this is the answer : t-if="l.product_uom_qty % 1 == 0"